# Getting exception while connecting to pipeline debugger

Tags: intershop

I am getting below exception while connecting to pipeline debugger. I tried to re start application server / HTTP service / system as well but no luck.  Any one have faced the same problem .

> com.intershop.beehive.core.rapi.soap.ConnectException:
>   http://localhost:80/INTERSHOP/servlet/WFS/SOAP/-/SessionMgmtService;
>   nested exception is: 
>     com.intershop.beehive.core.rapi.soap.SOAPException: SOAP-Stub:
>   response payload is not wellformed    at
>   com.intershop.beehive.core.rapi.soap.SOAPStub.getPayload(SOAPStub.java:381)
>     at
>   com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.bos.session.SessionMgmtService_SOAPStub.setTimeout(SessionMgmtService_SOAPStub.java:130)
>     at
>   com.intershop.studio.server.suite6.remote.emc.Session.(Session.java:111)
>     at
>   com.intershop.studio.server.suite6.remote.RemoteSuite6ServerInstance.doConnect(RemoteSuite6ServerInstance.java:113)
>     at
>   com.intershop.studio.server.remote.services.impl.AbstractRemoteServerInstance$1.run(AbstractRemoteServerInstance.java:52)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56) Caused
>   by: com.intershop.beehive.core.rapi.soap.SOAPException: SOAP-Stub:
>   response payload is not wellformed    at
>   com.intershop.beehive.core.rapi.soap.SOAPStub.getPayload(SOAPStub.java:368)
>     ... 5 more

Comment: Is the shop is reachable by the browser on port 80?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your pipeline debugger settings?